How to prove that the limit at an asymptote of a rational function doesn't exist?
I want to prove that the limit of a rational function $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ as $x\to a$ doesn't exist when $f(a)\neq 0$ and $g(a)=0$.
$$\nexists L\in\mathbb{R}\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\text{dom}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})(0<|x-a|<\delta\implies|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|<\epsilon)$$
or
$${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}\text{ is undefined}$$
Where $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are polynomials.
I'm at an absolute brain fart here and can't seem to connect the dots for this proof nor can I find it online. I know the limit doesn't exist by just looking at a graph. However I can't seem to get this one started.
My thought process.
Polynomials are continuous at every point so ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to n}f(x)}=f(n)$ and ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to n}g(x)}=g(n)$ forall $n$.
I also know that if I can prove that either ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a^-}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$ or ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a^+}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$ is undefined, then so is ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}}$.
So if I have to prove: $$\nexists L\in\mathbb{R}\forall\epsilon>0\exists\delta>0\forall x\in\text{dom}(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)})(0<\pm(x-a)<\delta\implies|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L|<\epsilon)$$
I am also thinking of a double induction proof on the polynomial degree of $f$ and $g$.
Proving ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a_0x^0}{b_0x^0}}$ through ${\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a}\frac{a_nx^n}{b_0x^0}}$ are undefined and then repeat with the denominator.
I feel like all these clues will add up to the answer but I can't seem to put it together. Perhaps there is an easier way I'm missing.

Do you mean $f(a) \ne 0$ and $g(a) = 0$?  Then $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ and $\lim_{x \to a} g(a) = 0$. Hint: If $\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ existed, then consider $$\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = \left(\lim_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \right) \left(\lim_{x \to a} g(x) \right) $$

Thank you. I get it now.

There's a slick trick (the core step of which I've highlighted in red) that makes quick work of this problem. The statement to be proved is

Suppose $g(a) = 0$. If $f(a)\ne 0$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ does not exist.

This is equivalent to the contrapositive

Suppose $g(a) = 0$. If $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$ exists, then $f(a)=0$.

This equivalent statement can be proved as follows:
Set $L = \displaystyle\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$. Then
$$
\lim_{x\to a} \color{red}{f(x)} = \lim_{x\to a} \biggl( \color{red}{\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} g(x)} \biggr) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \cdot \lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L\cdot 0 = 0.
$$
But the polynomial $f(x)$ is continuous everywhere, so $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = 0$ implies $f(a) = 0$.

Thank you!  This really helped.

I also noticed this proof would apply to any two functions continuous at every point.
